# Spinner that returns multiple value on selected?

Tags: android, spinner

is it possible for a `Spinner` to return multiple values or class object on selected?

For example I have a Spinner of Laptop models. When selected I want it to return `LaptopSpecs` object that contains size, weight, processor, etc. Then use it to display the information in the view below it.

Thanks

Comment: store the specs in database and compare via spinner selection value and display it

Comment: Thanks, but is `Spinner` really can't return object?

Comment: Did you get the string value while selecting the spinner

Comment: Yeah, I only got single String value. I want it to return a class object

Comment: there is no need for multiple value in your case. you only need the id of the selected item and a lookup thing to get the full object back.

Comment: By using the selecting String value compare through the database which contains the specs of laptop and display it where do you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you are populating your spinner.

If you are pulling the data from a database in a cursor, what you are trying to do is easy.

As a matter of fact, using a database, there's a couple ways you can do it:

1) You simply pull *all* the necessary data you need to create the object into your cursor (kinda heavy load on the front end), and when a selection is made (fromthe single bit of data displayed in the spinner), you use the cursor position reference in the `onItemSlected` method to pull the related data from the cursor and pack it into your object.

2) You pull only the piece of data to display in the spinner and when a selection is made, use the database row id in the `onItemSelected` method to fetch the rest of the data for your object from the database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So is option 2 much more efficient? Because I think option 1 is slow at first but fast after that

Comment: I would say option 2 is the better since you load far less data overall.  In option 1 you are laoding everything and only using a bit, in option two you are only loading what you need to make the app run.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, there is no multi-select `Spinner`. You are welcome to use a multi-select list `AlertDialog` to allow the user to make their selection(s), but you will need to decide for yourself how you want to render those selection(s) when the dialog is not on the screen.

Comment: Sorry maybe my question a bit confusing. What I want is a `Spinner` that returns an object (or multiple values) instead of single String.

Comment: @DarcCode: A `Spinner` doesn't "return" anything. It is a class, not a method. The selection the user makes is not necessarily a `String` -- it is whatever data model is wrapped by your `Adapter` (strings, restaurants, missile types, hats, etc.). That is all naturally a part of the existing `Spinner`. What is not possible with the standard `Spinner` is for the user to choose more than one item from the list.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that with custom adapter we can return any object